# How to get registry and file exclusions from UWF using WMI query in C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, wmi, uwf, uwfmgr

I want to get all registry exclusion and file exclusion from UWF, using the WMI.

I've already tried to invoke GetExclusions methods from UWF_RegistryFilter class but of no luck.

I am looking forward to a working sample code, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The difficult part is to read the out parameters from the method result. There is no appropriate documentation available on [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-registryfilter) and it's difficult to guess how ManagementBaseObject can be utilized for reading the out parameters.

In order to reach to a solution, I tried to develop an understanding of how WMI makes use of out parameters based on other well-documented wmi samples. Please use the C# code below, I hope it helps:

```
public static void GetRegistryExclusions()
    {

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
        using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_RegistryFilter",
        null))
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                ManagementBaseObject[] result = (ManagementBaseObject[])mo.InvokeMethod("GetExclusions", null, null).Properties["ExcludedKeys"].Value;

                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (var r in result)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(r.GetPropertyValue("RegistryKey"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note/Request** Request someone with [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) to create and link following tags so that it becomes easier for people like me to request solutions/answer questions on stackoverflow.

1. UWF
2. UWFMGR

Answer (score 2):

Found Manoj's answer only after I figured it out myself from a [hint on a microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d29513e-9690-4f25-9191-670931163e30/how-to-access-wmi-method-with-output-array-parameter-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral), when I wanted to put my code on SO. Therefore adding keywords Unified Write Filter and UWF_Volume (does it work like this?).

I used a slightly shorter syntax to access the properties, and also return the excluded files as the OP asked. I tried to make it as robust as possible, as it seems that there are some invalid volume entries. If someone has a clue what they are, please let me know.

```
public static string GetFilterDetail()
{
  string details = "";
  string detailsCurrent = "";
  string detailsNext = "";
  try
  {
    // Get WMI provider for UWF
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\StandardCimv2\embedded");
    var managementPath = scope.Path.Path;
    using (ManagementClass volumeFilterClass = new ManagementClass(managementPath, "UWF_Volume", null))
    {
      var volumeFilters = volumeFilterClass?.GetInstances();
      if (volumeFilters != null && volumeFilters.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (ManagementObject volumeFilter in volumeFilters)
        {
          if (volumeFilter != null)
          {
            // Now we have access to the Volume's WMI provider class

            // First check if this is a valid Volume instance, as from trial and error it seems that is not always the case.
            // Some invalid/undocumented instances throw a Not Found ManagementException on the GetExclusions method.
            // Some also throw a NullReferenceException on mo.GetPropertyValue("Protected"), but that covers less cases.
            bool isInstanceValid = true;
            try
            {
              volumeFilter.InvokeMethod("GetExclusions", null, null);
            }
            catch (ManagementException ex)
            {
              if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("not found"))
                isInstanceValid = false;
              else throw ex;
            }

            if (isInstanceValid)
            {
              bool currentSession = ((bool)volumeFilter.GetPropertyValue("CurrentSession"));
              string driveLetter = (string)volumeFilter.GetPropertyValue("DriveLetter");
              bool isProtected = ((bool)volumeFilter.GetPropertyValue("Protected"));
              string detail = "Volume " + driveLetter + " is " + (isProtected ? "protected" : "not protected") + ".\n";
              detail += "Excluded files:\n";

              ManagementBaseObject outParams = volumeFilter.InvokeMethod("GetExclusions", null, null);
              if (outParams != null)
              {
                var excludedItems = (ManagementBaseObject[])outParams["ExcludedFiles"];
                if (excludedItems != null)
                {
                  foreach (var excludedItem in excludedItems)
                  {
                    detail += "    " + driveLetter + excludedItem["FileName"] + "\n";
                  }
                }
                else detail += "    [No excluded files]\n";
              }

              if (currentSession)
                detailsCurrent += detail;
              else
                detailsNext += detail;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    using (ManagementClass registryFilterClass = new ManagementClass(managementPath, "UWF_RegistryFilter", null))
    {
      var registryFilters = registryFilterClass?.GetInstances();
      if (registryFilters != null && registryFilters.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (ManagementObject registryFilter in registryFilters)
        {
          if (registryFilter != null)
          {
            // Now we have access to the RegistryFilter's WMI provider class

            bool currentSession = ((bool)registryFilter.GetPropertyValue("CurrentSession"));
            string detail = "Excluded registry keys:\n";

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = registryFilter.InvokeMethod("GetExclusions", null, null);
            if (outParams != null)
            {
              var excludedItems = (ManagementBaseObject[])outParams["ExcludedKeys"];
              if (excludedItems != null)
              {
                foreach (var excludedItem in excludedItems)
                {
                  detail += "    " + excludedItem["RegistryKey"] + "\n";
                }
              }
              else detail += "    [No excluded registry keys]\n";
            }

            if (currentSession)
              detailsCurrent += detail;
            else
              detailsNext += detail;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    details += ex.ToString();
  }

  details += "\nNOTE: These settings are only active if the Write Filter is Enabled\n"
          + "\nCURRENT SETTINGS:\n" + detailsCurrent
          + "\nNEXT SETTINGS: (after next reboot)\n" + detailsNext;

  return details;
}
```

Example output:

[image: example output]